# Make docker container run forever while being able to gracefully stop

Tags: bash, docker, dockerfile

I am trying to create a docker container. It is supposed to run forever in background. But whenever I press Ctrl+C or `docker stop`, it should close without wasting any further time.

My current code

```
#RUN trap 'echo $excode' EXIT HUP INT QUIT PIPE TERM
ENTRYPOINT while :; do read; done
#ENTRYPOINT trap "exit 1" SIGTERM SIGHUP && tail -f /dev/null & wait && exit 0
```

I can make it run forever but for some reason my script is not receiving TRAP events. Any clue how to fix that.

Answer (score 5):

You could consider using (with docker 1.9+) [`STOPSIGNAL`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#stopsignal) in your Dockerfile.

> The STOPSIGNAL instruction sets the system call signal that will be sent to the container to exit.
>   This signal can be a valid unsigned number that matches a position in the kernel’s syscall table, for instance 9, or a signal name in the format SIGNAME, for instance SIGKILL.

But for a script managing such a signal, see "[Trapping signals in Docker containers](https://medium.com/@gchudnov/trapping-signals-in-docker-containers-7a57fdda7d86#.r5371l1zb)" and its `program.sh` to orchestrate other non-PID1 processes.

Answer (score 3):

Start your container with the flags : `-t` & `-i` :

```
docker run -it --name=<container_name> <image>:<tag>
```

This will enable you to exit using `ctrl+c`

See this [docker issue](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/2838) for more info.

Comment: I would add at the end _/bin/bash_ as then It opens the bash command line.

Comment: Am using docker version 17.05, -it option works with Ctrl + C, ie the container shell awaits till Ctrl + C is entered.Once entered, the container process exits. This is due to the use of -i in the option that makes the container process's STDIN open.On inputting Ctrl +C, the while loop exits, and the container process also dies with it.